# what's the meaning of "first.next = second.next;"

Tags: java

This code is going to swap nodes in pairs, what's the meaning of  "first.next = second.next;"?
example：if given 1->2->3->4,  should return the list as 2->1->4->3.

```
class Solution {
public ListNode swapPairs(ListNode head) {
    ListNode dummy  = new ListNode(0);
    dummy.next = head;
    ListNode curr = dummy;


    while(curr.next!=null && curr.next.next!=null){
      ListNode first = curr.next;
      ListNode second = curr.next.next;
      first.next = second.next;
        curr.next = second;
      curr.next.next = first;
      curr = curr.next.next;
    }
    return dummy.next;
}
```

}

Comment: provide us class definition of `ListNode `

Comment: Please add more detail to your question.  The naive answer that probably doesn't answer your core question is: "It assigns the value of `second.next` to `first.next`".  But that isn't what you're asking.  Please be exhaustive in what you are asking.

Comment: Why not run the code in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Since we know `dummy.next` is the head of the list and we know `curr` is the same as `dummy` then we know `first = curr.next;` means first is the head of the list. 
So it follows that `second = curr.next.next` tells us that `second` is the element right after the first element in the list.

The goal of this function is it swap the elements in pairs. Currently the list looks like:

```
curr -> first -> second -> second.next -> second.next.next -> ...
```

However when we perform `first.next = second.next;` the order changes and we get:

```
curr -> first -> second.next
```

Then the line `curr.next = second;` changes the list again and gives us:

```
 curr -> second -> first -> second.next
```

Thus the order of the pair is switched. The remaining code just moves curr the next pair to get ready to swap them.